# Unable to change theme in VS Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

am not getting any error or anything, but VS code by default always switches to a Dark+ (default dark), even if in my system setting I have selected Light theme (I have a MacBook Air). This is too much frustrating and I also uninstalled and installed VS Code 2-3 times and am unable to change the behaviour. Please let me know if you need any additional info with this question, I will provide it.

An additional point on this problem, when I press `CMD +,` to open setting, and under appearance, I change the Color Theme, it let me change. And then when I open a file (a python file suppose) or just switch to an opened file it changes back to Dark+ (default dark). I don't know how to solve this behaviour. Please help.

Comment: I have tried ```CMD KT``` also  and it always switches back to default dark mode.

Comment: You have probably selected `User` instead of `Workspace`. Click on `WorkSpace` and make your setttings accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset workbench settings to default and then added the following to settings.json and it solved my problem.

```
    "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark Default",
    "window.autoDetectColorScheme": true,
    "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "GitHub Dark Default",
    "workbench.preferredLightColorTheme": "GitHub Light Default",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think VS Code is just doesn't follow the system theme (I observed this in my Windows 10 machine). Also `cmd+,` is not the place to change VS code theme.

You can try <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and enter `>color theme` to select a theme.

[image]

Comment: I have tried cmd KT and it always switches back to the default dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

VS code doesn't follow system theme, do cmd + K, then let go of K while holding cmd and press T. Or you can cmd + K THEN cmd + T. There you will get a menu where you will get your color options.

Comment: I have tried this also, it always switched back to the default dark theme.